# Shifting of origin

Tags: geometry, circles, coordinate-systems

Find the equation of straight line joining the point $(2,2)$ to the points in which the straight line  $y=mx+c$ cuts the circle, $x^2 + y^2 =2ax+2ay$. Hence find the condition that these points may subtend a right angle at the point $(2,2)$. I am sure if the point in the question were to be origin, I could use homogenization to solve the problem, So I wanted to ask to solve this problem should I shift the origin from $(2,2)$ to $(0,0)$ like changing the equations to $(y-2)=m(x-2)$ and  $(x-2)^2+(y-2)^2=2a(x-2)(y-2)$ and the solve the question?

Please let me know if my method is correct

Comment: Shifting to the origin:

$(x+2)^2 + (y+2)^2 =2a(x+2)+2a(y+2)$ and $y+2=m(x+2)+c,$

Homogenizing:

$x^2+y^2+(4-2a)x(-mx+y)/(2-2m-c)+(4-2a)y(-mx+y)/(2-2m-c)+(8-8a)((-mx+y)/(2-2m-c))^2$ or $\frac{(4m^2+(4c+4a-16)m+c^2+(2a-8)c-12a+20)y^2
 +((8-4a)m^2+((4-2a)c+24a-32)m+(2a-4)c-4a+8)xy
 +((20-12a)m^2+((8-2a)c+4a-16)m+c^2-4c+4)x^2}
 {4m^2+(4c-8)m+c^2-4c+4}$

Comment: shouldn't we subtract to shift origin?

Comment: No, because shifting back would be subtracting. e.g. $(y+2-2)=m(x+2-2)+c$

Comment: I didn't get you, I am sorry will you please elaborate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: To shift $(2,2)$ to the origin, remember that $x=(x+2)-2$ and $y=(y+2)-2$ [image: shift]